# how to speed up view port display?

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, rigidbody

I have a mesh with a lot of vertices. When I tried applying the armature and animating the rig, the mesh is extremely slow and I can barely animate any mesh.

Is there a way to speed up the render view port so I can at least animate the mesh?

[image: Blender screenshot showing a Scene in mesh editing mode, containing a shark object and an area selected near its tail.]

Comment: You need to retopologize your mesh in order to make it low-poly

Comment: thanks for the respond , how can i actually make this ? best regard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

High-poly mesh are super tedious to manage and animate, you need to make your mesh low-poly. There are at least 3 solutions, depending on your need and on your current topology:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Un-Subdivide* will work fine if your topology is already clean (made of quads), tweak the parameters in the *Operator Box*.
- In the *Object Data* panel > *Remesh* > try the *Quadriflow Remesh* operation. It probably won't give the perfect topology but it could be enough for your needs. Note that there are other remesh tools, like the app called *Instant Mesh*, that could give a better result.
- Real retopology. It's the most tedious solution but it's necessary if you want to have a good topology. It consists on manually recreating a low-poly object that you'll snap on the high-poly. See for example [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2GNyEUvpD4) by CG Boost.

Also, once you have your low-poly version, you can give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier in order to make it look rounder. Put the modifier under the *Armature* modifier and don't apply it if you want to keep a low-poly object.

And if you need to keep some details of you high-poly, you need to bake its normals (lots of tutorials on this topic as well).